# Disable RPi 3 Wifi

Tags: osmc

Hi I know there are a few questions asked very similar to the above, but can someone please provide a full methodology for disabling the wifi via the blacklisting method, as i dont know where to begin.

Comment: Wait, do you want to block other devices or disable Wifi? These are different things...

Comment: Just completely disable the built in wifi as I have a 5GHz usb dongle

Answer (score 2):

In [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3) you can find the answer

Disable drivers by editing the file `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` and add:

```
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmutil
```

---

**Step-by-step**

Backup the file before editing `sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf.backup`

1. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`
2. Edit text
3. Press F3 to save changes
4. Press F2 to exit

Comment: Yes but how do I do that step by step

Comment: Open file /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf and just add 2 strings.

Comment: With what program?

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`. Edit text. Press F3 for saving. Press F2 to exit.