# How PowerOff Bluetooth on Pi4?

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, wireless, raspberry-pi-os-buster

There's some information around disabling Bluetooth interface on boot for Raspberry Pi3 and previous, as described on this page: [Disable power on Wifi and Bluetooth interfaces during boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53149/disable-power-on-wifi-and-bluetooth-interfaces-during-boot)

The same applies to Raspberry Pi**4**?
In other words... should I use

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

or a similar command like this one:

```
dtoverlay=pi4-disable-bt
```

So... How properly disable it?

(I'm running Raspbian Buster).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look in the /boot/overlays/README file you will see that the folk at RPF/RPT have tried to sort this out by actually renaming the file:

> This overlay has been renamed disable-bt

Unfortunately, the internet never keeps up  so you will not find a pi4-disable-bt option.  You can continue to use the pi3 command but I would use the `disable-bt` just in case they remove the pi3 version in the future.

To be honest though, why bother?  The power saving is so minor and another device transmitting in the air makes zero difference to the transmission speeds...

Comment: In fact, I just want to fully disable bluetooth from my system (for security purposes)... But I think it would be nice to Power it Off

Comment: This may interest you https://learn.pi-supply.com/make/how-to-save-power-on-your-raspberry-pi/#disable-wi-fi-bluetooth shows possible power savings and notes the disable turns it off.