# Raspberry Pi 3 Wireless Question

Tags: wifi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3. 32 GB edition. The wireless feature was working fine...now it is not. It appears to be connected to the wireless network at work, but typing in a URL results in no result. Also, how do I turn off the wireless feature? Eventually, I will not need wireless capability.

Comment: There are several options on disabling WiFi on the Pi 3 [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3). In order to diagnose your problem you're going to have to edit some more information into your question (*don't use comments*) - can you ping other devices on your network, can you ping external websites, can you ping the [DNS servers listed in /etc/resolv.conf](http://superuser.com/a/617797)?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of ifconfig, also include the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit any static IP configurations that might be wrong and could be the problem?

To disable Wi-Fi you can edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf by adding the following lines:

```
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmutil
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks very much the blacklist information helped