# Turning off Wifi/ Bluetooth module

Tags: pi-3, wifi, power, bluetooth, wireless

I have a cluster of Raspberry Pi 3 machines in a cluster. To reduce power consumption I would like to turn off the wireless modules. I have learnt that HDMI can be switched off with the *tvservice* command:

```
sudo tvservice -o
```

Is there a similar command for wifi/bluetooth?

There is a similar question which discusses disabling wifi ([Disable WiFi (wlan0) on Pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720)) but it does not specifically request the power conservation aspect which is what I am concerned with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable WiFi (wlan0) on Pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3)

Comment: NOT DUPLICATE The question may be similar, but the answer is OBSOLETE, and is about TOTALLY disabling WiFi NOT turning it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rfkill sounds like what you are after.

```
$ rfkill list 

$ rfkill block (device no)

$ rfkill unblock (device no)
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/881572/479642

Answer (score 4):

You CAN use device id (which may be appropriate if you had multiple adaptors), but the Foundation recommended method is:-

To turn off wifi, `rfkill block wifi`; to turn it on, `rfkill unblock wifi`.
For Bluetooth, `rfkill block bluetooth` and `rfkill unblock bluetooth`.