# Creating a Network for 1 client device with wifi

Tags: access-point, hotspot

Firstly, my apologies for using any incorrect terminology.

**What I have:**

A Raspberry Pi Zero W running Buster with a connected e-paper display, currently using a USB 2 Ethernet adapter to get it set up.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I'm trying to set up a Wifi Access Point (Hot spot?) on the Pi, so that one device (smartphone) can connect to the wifi served by the Raspberry Pi (via credentials passed using a QR code displayed on the ePaper display).
Then, once the device has connected, allow the device to acceess a page hosted on the Pi. Literally all I need is some guidance to help me get started with step 3 below.

**What I DO NOT need/want**

There will be no need to have an internet connection when the Hot Spot (AP) is active.

**The Purpose**

When the Pi detects that the current internet connection (on WiFi) has disconnected from the internet, It will:

1. Get a list of available WiFi hotspots in range - *Completed*
2. Disable the current wpa_supplicant configuration - *should be easy enough to do*
3. Enable the Hotspot (with random credentials) - *Not sure where to start with this one*
4. Draw a QR code to allow **ONE** device to connect to the hotspot. - *This should be easy enough to do*
5. Wait for a device to connect - *This should also be easy enough to do*
6. Display a new QR code to allow the smart device to load up the web page displaying the WiFi hotspots gathered in step 1 above. - *This should also be easy enough to do*
7. Allow the user to select the new network, and then enter the passphrase for the new network on their device. - *This should also be easy enough to accomplish*
8. Disable the Hot Spot and connect to the new network with the credentials provided in the step above - *Should also be easy enough to do*

**What I've found so far**

I've found instructions on setting up hotspots to allow devices to connect to Raspberry Pis and then route the traffic through to the internet on a different interface (connect to wifi and then use the eth0 to connect to the net) using IP Tables.

Also the use of dnsmasq

**What I'm trying to avoid**

What I do not want is a bloated system running too many services that are not required. And so I'm reluctant to start installing services/apps that will not be needed. The Pi Zero W is not a beast of a PC, so, I'm trying to keep it lightweight.

**Additional**

I've had a look at [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96399/automatically-toggle-pi-zero-hot-spot-wifi-client-off-and-on), But it has link rot and does not give any insight into what I am trying to achieve.

I think that [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/connect-android-smartphone-with-wi-fi-direct-to-a-raspberry-pi) goes a little overboard by setting up a WiFi Direct with many available clients and requiring the installation of nmap (remember, I'm trying to keep unnessesary installations to a minimum)

I've had a look at a few other resources, but all of them seem intenet on setting up a gateway to allow the Pi to act as an internet hotspot, to allow someone to connect to it wirelessly and then access the internet via the Pi's ethernet. (Internet -> eth0 -> Pi -> wlan0 -> wireless device).