# showing error for use the command sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower on

Tags: wifi

For making remote ssh connection on raspberry pi 3B (os raspbian), it need to close wifi connection (to use only wired connection instead), I have found the command on [SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/disable-wifi-wlan0-on-pi-3) is

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower off
```

But the problem is now I cant switch on back the wifi. I have used the code

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower on
```

it shows error,

```
Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B27) :
    GET failed on device wlan0 ; Input/output error.
```

Now what is the way to get the wifi again?

Comment: [Is this relevant?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62166/siocsifflags-operation-not-possible-due-to-rf-kill)

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. There are much better solutions to your problem than fiddling with low level powering the interface. It may also produce other error messages by the operating system expecting a powered interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For making remote ssh connection on raspberry pi 3B (os raspbian), it
>   need to close wifi connection. (to use only wired connection instead)

You can do it by `ifplugd` package with filling the `/etc/network/interfaces` out. Follow [this link](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2013-07-31-raspberry-pi-networking.php) to do that. You can be enabled to disable wireless networks automatically when a wired cabled plugged.

---

> But the problem is now I cant switch on back the wifi.

However, if you are concerned about this method, you should try `sudo rfkill unblock wifi` before that command. Also, [check this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=161336) link out.